# How to pass a database engine/connection to a multiprocessing pool ? can't pickle _thread._local objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, database-connection

I want to execute sql on `task` function efficiently. But I don't know how!
I am currently calling a dumb function from `task` that creates a connection with `with snowflake.connector.connect(some_creds_here) as con:`, *creates a connection for every query*.

I tried sending the engine object to the `task` but it had the same response. I created this basic structure out of a big module for debugging.

```
def get_connection():
    engine = create_engine(
        'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/'.format(
            user="user",
            password="password",
            account="us-east-1",
        )
    )
    try:
        connection = engine.connect()
        return connection, engine
    finally:
        pass

def task(con):
    con = con.connect()
    print(con.execute('select current_version()').fetchone())

def main():
    connection, engine = get_connection()
    iterable = [(engine) for x in range(10)]
    with Pool() as p:
        for _ in p.imap_unordered(task, iterable):
            ...
    con.close()
    engine.dispose()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the error response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "service\ECR\file_conversion_worker\mock.py", line 26, in main
    for _ in p.imap_unordered(task, iterable):
  File "\AppData\Continuum\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 748, in next
    raise value
  File "\AppData\Continuum\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "\AppData\Continuum\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "\AppData\Continuum\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

Edit: Corrected thread pool to multiprocessing pool

Comment: That's not a thread pool, that's a multiprocessing pool.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think you're going to get much of a speed up using multi-threading/multi-processing with database connections.  Not that it's impossible, but it's rarely the right way to go.

Comment: @jordanm thank you!

Comment: @FiddleStix Would creating a global connection object be an efficient way? I just tried that, it is creating a new connection for every query as well, is it fine?

Comment: I would create one connection object per thread. Connection objects are ok to use for multiple queries, but you should limit reuse of cursor objects.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks a ton!